# Detecting schema change in database

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there a standard way of detecting if database schema changed? Particularly I am interested in knowing whether any table schema in a database changed or whether any new table got added since I last checked (defined frequency of check) ? One crude way of doing that is to keep polling the cluster for this information using `.show database schema` at fixed interval and also storing this result for comparison for the next check. But is there a way provided by ADX for doing something like this? Some sort of event trigger that I can listen to as and when this change happens instead of polling the cluster every now and then ? I don't expect database schema changes to happen frequently but they can happen abruptly so it is overhead to keep checking now and then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no event trigger of that sort as of this writing.

- You can submit a feature request for that @ https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice.

With current means, you can periodically use `.show journal` to monitor for any schema changes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/journal

You can also make sure all schema changes go through source control, and none are manually done on your cluster - so that you end up with tighter control over the E2E process. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/tools-integrations-overview#source-control-integration